# Mongoose custom validation failing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my application I am trying to run some custom validations on mongoose, all I want is to be able to make sure that ratings from a particular user should not exceed more than once, I have tried a couple of things, and the code to begin with return true and false correctly but the error is not triggered. Here is my code

```
RatingSchema.path('email').validate(function (email) {
  var Rating = mongoose.model('Rating');
  //console.log('i am being validated')
  //console.log('stuff: ' + this.email+ this.item)
  Rating.count({email: this.email, item: this.item},function(err,count){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      if(count===0){
        //console.log(count)
        return true; 
      }
      else {
        //console.log('Count: in else(failing)'+ count)
        return false;
      }
    }    
  }); 
},'Item has been already rated by you')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a [validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) that performs an asynchronous operation (like your `Rating.count` call), your validator function needs to accept a second parameter which is a callback that you call to provide the true or false result as you can't just return async results.

```
RatingSchema.path('email').validate(function (email, respond) {
  var Rating = mongoose.model('Rating');
  Rating.count({email: this.email, item: this.item},function(err,count){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      if(count===0){
        respond(true); 
      }
      else {
        respond(false);
      }
    }    
  });
},'Item has been already rated by you');
```